# I can't stream live video from youtube, but normal video are working in android

Tags: android

I can't stream live video from youtube, but normal video are working in android.

```
    public class ShowYoutube extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    @Override   
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_youtube);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Key, this);
  }

  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo("fsDUeIkbePQ");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }

}
```

But using this code i can stream normal video files but not live youtube video files.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is not working? Are you trying to load the file directly from the YouTube URL?

Comment: Getting message unsupported video format.. Iam loading directly from youtube.. not using any third party sites.

Comment: What is the file path you are using.

Comment: fsDUeIkbePQ is the id of the video i have used.  i mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsDUeIkbePQ

Comment: Right, what is the actual URL is it http://www.youtube.com/fsDUeIkbePQ? If so that is returning a web page and not a video.

Comment: The solution you provided not working...but it was working for normal vedios like http://...../sample.mp4... Not for youtube vedio.. App closing automatically when doing like this.. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: So what is the actual full file path you are using? Not just the youtube id?

Comment: in my code   "player.cueVideo("fsDUeIkbePQ");" is contains the id of the video.

Comment: any one else for helping me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try VideoView instead to stream videos a sshown below:

```
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.app_video_view);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            VideoStreamActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoStreamActivity.this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
     String str = "VIDEO URL";
        Log.d(TAG, "url: "+str);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

and in your layout file add this:

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/app_video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Regards,
Tahir

Comment: Its working partially for normal videos like video we stored in some places in network... Do you have any other solution Tahir?

Comment: can you provide an example link of a video that you want to stream so i can check why its not working

Comment: the link you have provided is a live stream link which will only work when live streaming is available at the moment there is no live streaming and even on youtube its not working.
Hope you got my point if not let me know your concerns.

Comment: I had sent that link for sample only...actual link with live streaming happens also not working...

Answer (score 0):

I've got a slightly different problem. I am able play some of the live videos. I've looked into the stream details and I haven't found anything. I have something in mind that might cause "unsupported video format" - DRM. Some of the videos can have DRM implemented in some way that cannot be verified by the api. The other possible reason: the live video id that you'd like to play does not exist in a valid video format(This is the most reasonable cause for the error but I could not find any related docs).

Comment: may be the same as you said...bcz i've also faced the same ..few live videos were working fine.DRM is a video formate??

Comment: DRM - Digital Right Management are videos with digital copyrights. 
Other reasons can be that the video, that you're trying to play is not available for your contry/region or it also may be paid content.

Another possible problem: live video is over. I still cannot find a way to detect it programatically.